# Which is the best way to compare enums in Java? Why I should use == and not .equals() method?

Tags: java

Which is the best way to compare enums in Java?

Comment: It's a matter of taste. No strong argument exists either way. Where I work we are using `==`. For code I post on Stack Overflow I tend to use `.equals()` not to lead anyone to think you can genrally use `==` between objects.

Comment: See source, [`Enum.java`](https://github.com/bpupadhyaya/openjdk-8/blob/master/jdk/src/share/classes/java/lang/Enum.java#L142)